# Hiding a button in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a ListView populated by `Activity` having `TextView` On clicking the item in the list view the subsequent `TextView` in the relevant activity is displayed.

want to put a `Button` in the Activity having `TextView`,But apparently the button also appears in the `ListView`.And the On item click listener on the `ListView` doesn't respond.

So Is there any way to just get the `TextView` on `ListView` and not the Button.Thereby when a user clicks the item on the `ListView` ,`TextView` along with the button is also displayed.

Any guidance in the right path would be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial visibility of your TextView and Button in your list item layout to "gone" and reference both views in your adapter and set their visibility to View.Visible OnItemClick.